# Error while installing package 21cmFAST: Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully

Tags: python, github, pip, package

I am trying to install a python package using the instructions given [here](https://github.com/yitiansun/DM21cm). When I am running pip install . in my project directory I am getting the following error,

> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
> exit code: 1
> [37 lines of output]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in 
> main()
> File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
> json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
> return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6_pvzx2q/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 366, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
> self.run_setup()
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6_pvzx2q/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
> exec(code, locals())
> File "", line 43, in 
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6_pvzx2q/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line 103, in setup
> return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6_pvzx2q/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 147, in setup
> _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6_pvzx2q/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 303, in *init*
> _Distribution.**init**(self, dist_attrs)
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6_pvzx2q/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 283, in *init*
> self.finalize_options()
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6_pvzx2q/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 654, in finalize_options
> ep(self)
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6_pvzx2q/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools_scm/_integration/setuptools.py", line 121, in infer_version
> _assign_version(dist, config)
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6_pvzx2q/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools_scm/_integration/setuptools.py", line 56, in _assign_version
> _version_missing(config)
> File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6_pvzx2q/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools_scm/_get_version_impl.py", line 112, in _version_missing
> raise LookupError(
> LookupError: setuptools-scm was unable to detect version for /home/user/21cmFAST-master.
>
> Make sure you're either building from a fully intact git repository or PyPI tarballs. Most other sources (such as GitHub's tarballs, a git checkout without the .git folder) don't contain the necessary metadata and will not work.
>
> For example, if you're using pip, instead of https://github.com/user/proj/archive/master.zip use git+https://github.com/user/proj.git#egg=proj
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> error: metadata-generation-failed
>
> Encountered error while generating package metadata.
> See above for output.

Can somebody tell me how to resolve this?

I couldn't find a solution to this particular problem anywhere

Comment: Did you download or cloned the repository using `git`?

Comment: I downloaded the repository

Comment: I just now cloned the repository and the error is gone....Thanks!